# Android Camera Is Acting Weird

Tags: android, camera

I am using Camera in the Android SDK for the first time, and like with most first times problems ensue...

I have my activity in portrait but my camera is oriented VERY weird. Its literally flipping the image on its side. So if I stick my finger in from the top it comes in from the left on the preview... I have been tweeking my code for ages now and nothing is changing it. Here is my preview class:

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int f, int w, int h) {
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setPreviewSize(w,h);
    params.set("orientation", "portrait");
    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder h) {
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(h);
        camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera c) {
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    //if(!(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MemeMe/Temp/").exists())){
                    //  
                    //}
                    File memeTempPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MemeMe/Temp/");
                    File[] tempFiles = memeTempPath.listFiles();
                    for(int i = 0; i < tempFiles.length; i++){
                        tempFiles[i].delete();
                    }
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(String.format(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MemeMe/Temp/"+System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    fos.write(data);
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Preview.this.invalidate();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now here is my activity:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    preview = new Preview(this);
    previewL = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.cameraLayout);
    previewL.addView(preview);
```

I am rather confused by this issue. I thought the preview is supposed to change based off the orientation... I also tried to do params.setRotation() and did about every rotation i can think of 90,180,270,360 and it doesnt change it at all.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a preview, there is a different method to adjust camera image rotation... it is thoroughly described in android documentation for [setDisplayOrientation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29). It is available since API level 8.

Update for 2.1 (level 7):

before 2.2 this code usually worked

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.set("orientation", "portrait"); // for some
parameters.set("rotation", 90);  // for others
// or parameters.setRotation(90);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

The problem is, that it seems it stopped working on some devices with 2.2+ so if you really need to support 2.1+, you can try the reflection for `setDisplayOrientation` and if it fails set the `"orientation"` parameter

```
void setDisplayOrientation(Camera camera, int angle){
  try {
    Method method = camera.getClass().getMethod("setDisplayOrientation", new Class[] { int.class });
    if (method != null) {
      method.invoke(camera, new Object[] { angle });
      return;
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {}
  Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
  parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
  parameters.set("rotation", 90);
  camera.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

Comment: I should have stated above, sorry, I am using API 7